# Replace the missing months & year in date column using python

Tags: python, pandas, date, replace

I have a dataframe with date column, some of the data are missing based on year and month. i have to display are the months for all the years in my dataset and the corresponding columns should display with zeros.

My dataframe looks like this

```
 Date    Churn    Churnrate  customerID
2008,01  726.0  0.542398        2763
2008,02  345.0  0.257751        1351
2012,11    NaN       NaN           6
2013,01    3.0  0.002241          24
2013,02   10.0  0.007471          34
2013,03   25.0  0.018678          73
2013,04   25.0  0.018678          75
2013,05   14.0  0.010459          61
2013,06   19.0  0.014195          69
2013,07   27.0  0.020172         103
2013,08   22.0  0.016436          79
2013,09   19.0  0.014195          70
2013,10   28.0  0.020919          83
2013,11   22.0  0.016436          78
2013,12   19.0  0.014195          75
2014,01   17.0  0.012701          63
2014,02   21.0  0.015689          55
2014,03    7.0  0.005230          66
2014,04   24.0  0.017931          86
2014,05   18.0  0.013448          90
2014,06   14.0  0.010459          50
```

For example in the year 2018, i have only two month records, but i want to display all the 12 months with 0s in the corresponding columns

My another dataframe looks like this

```
Months  Retention_Rate  Customer_Count
0  2008/01        0.145916             133
1  2008/02        0.924663             762
2  2008/03        0.074544              67
3  2014/07        0.058684              45
4  2014/08        0.069786              61
5  2014/09        0.076130              64
6  2014/10        0.061856              60
7  2014/11        0.082474              69
```

I have used the same answer which is given below

```
predicted_retention_rate = predicted_retention_rate.set_index('Months')
idx =(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(predicted_retention_rate.index.str.split('/', expand=True).levels)
        .map('/'.join))

final_retention_rate_predicted = predicted_retention_rate.reindex(idx, fill_value=0).rename_axis('Months').reset_index()
print (final_retention_rate_predicted)
```

But some of the months are missing in this output

```
Months  Retention_Rate  Customer_Count
0   2008/01        0.145916             133
1   2008/02        0.924663             762
2   2008/03        0.074544              67
3   2008/07        0.000000               0
4   2008/08        0.000000               0
5   2008/09        0.000000               0
6   2008/10        0.000000               0
7   2008/11        0.000000               0
8   2014/01        0.000000               0
9   2014/02        0.000000               0
10  2014/03        0.000000               0
11  2014/07        0.058684              45
12  2014/08        0.069786              61
13  2014/09        0.076130              64
14  2014/10        0.061856              60
15  2014/11        0.082474              69
```

Look at the above dataframe, year 2008 contains 01,02,03 but not 04,05,06 and the same in 2014. May i known where i went wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by new `index` created by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) `Date` to `MultiIndex` and `map` with `join`:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
idx =(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.str.split(',', expand=True).levels)
        .map(','.join))

df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0).rename_axis('Date').reset_index()
print (df.head())
      Date  Churn  Churnrate  customerID
0  2008,01  726.0   0.542398        2763
1  2008,02  345.0   0.257751        1351
2  2008,03    0.0   0.000000           0
3  2008,04    0.0   0.000000           0
4  2008,05    0.0   0.000000           0
```

EDIT: Solution with define all `Month`s by `range(1,13)`

```
df = df.set_index('Months')
years = df.index.str.split('/', expand=True).levels[0]
idx = (pd.MultiIndex.from_product([years, 
                                  pd.Series(range(1, 13)).astype(str).str.zfill(2)])
        .map('/'.join))

df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0).rename_axis('Date').reset_index()
print (df)
       Date  Retention_Rate  Customer_Count
0   2008/01        0.145916             133
1   2008/02        0.924663             762
2   2008/03        0.074544              67
3   2008/04        0.000000               0
4   2008/05        0.000000               0
5   2008/06        0.000000               0
6   2008/07        0.000000               0
7   2008/08        0.000000               0
8   2008/09        0.000000               0
9   2008/10        0.000000               0
10  2008/11        0.000000               0
11  2008/12        0.000000               0
12  2014/01        0.000000               0
13  2014/02        0.000000               0
14  2014/03        0.000000               0
15  2014/04        0.000000               0
16  2014/05        0.000000               0
17  2014/06        0.000000               0
18  2014/07        0.058684              45
19  2014/08        0.069786              61
20  2014/09        0.076130              64
21  2014/10        0.061856              60
22  2014/11        0.082474              69
23  2014/12        0.000000               0
```

If need replace the missing year and the corresponding  columns with zeros:

```
print (df)
Year   Churn_Count  Churn_Rate  Customer_Count                                        
2008       1071.0    0.800149             4114
2012          0.0    0.000000                6
2013        233.0    0.174075              824
2014        101.0    0.075458              410
```

Then use:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('Year')
        .reindex(range(2008, 2015), fill_value=0)
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
   Year  Churn_Count  Churn_Rate  Customer_Count
0  2008       1071.0    0.800149            4114
1  2009          0.0    0.000000               0
2  2010          0.0    0.000000               0
3  2011          0.0    0.000000               0
4  2012          0.0    0.000000               6
5  2013        233.0    0.174075             824
6  2014        101.0    0.075458             410
```

More dynamic solution for `reindex` by min and max year:

```
df1 = df.set_index('Year')
df1 = (df1.reindex(range(df1.index.min(), df1.index.max() + 1), fill_value=0)
          .reset_index())
print (df1)
   Year  Churn_Count  Churn_Rate  Customer_Count
0  2008       1071.0    0.800149            4114
1  2009          0.0    0.000000               0
2  2010          0.0    0.000000               0
3  2011          0.0    0.000000               0
4  2012          0.0    0.000000               6
5  2013        233.0    0.174075             824
6  2014        101.0    0.075458             410
```

Comment: It is working but displaying only these 5 records, what about remaining records? like 2008, 06,08 for all months and for other years?

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - use `print (df)`

Comment: I am sorry @jezrael i didnt notice that.

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - Thank you very much.

Comment: I am not getting all the months while using other data

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - Give me a sec.

Comment: Thanks. It worked, but we didnt specify the range for before data right? Why we need to give range for this

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - for first not specify, becasue year `2013` contains all months. Second solution is more general, so working if only one row DataFrame ;)

Comment: how to do this same process for yearwise calculation instead of months

Comment: can you help me to solve this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49355891/how-to-calculate-quarterly-wise-churn-and-retention-rate-using-python

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - Thanks you for coment. I like help you, but not sure what you need. In my opinion can you add `out = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-01','2015-05-01','2015-07-01','2015-10-01','2015-04-01','2015-12-01','2016-01-01','2016-02-01','2015-05-01', '2015-10-01']),
    'Churn': ['Yes'] * 8 + ['No'] * 2
})` to question with expected output? also be free modify it if necessary. Thanks.

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - And also what is `total_churn`?

Comment: total churn count in my churn column.

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - OK, so try change DataFrame from my commnet with expected output and I believe you get answer(s).

Comment: i have updated in your answer kindly check and let me know , if you need more information

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - It depends of data.  Btw, are datetimes parsed correctly?

Comment: Please check this and give me some suggestions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49412281/how-to-view-the-eliminated-data-after-preprocessing?noredirect=1#comment85826328_49412281

Answer (score 1):

I think that another simple approach could be this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":["2010-01", "2010-02", "2011-01"], 
                   "a": [1, 2, 3], 
                   "b":[0.2,-0.1,0.4]})
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
all_dates = pd.DataFrame({"date":pd.date_range(start=df["date"].min(), 
                                               end=df["date"].max(), 
                                               freq="MS")})
df = pd.merge(all_dates, df, how="left", on="date").fillna(0)
```

If `date` is your index you can just play with `.reset_index()` and `.set_index()`. Then if you want to maintain the same date format just add `df["date"] = df["date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m")`

Comment: df["date"] = df["date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m")

I am using this format only

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar Exactly as I stated at the end of my answer. Isn't this solution working in your case?