# How to calculate quarterly wise churn and retention rate using python

Tags: python

How to calculate quarterly wise churn and retention rate with date column using python. with date column i want to group that quarterly using python.

This is used to calculate the churn count groupby quarterly

```
quarterly_churn_yes = out.loc[out['Churn'] == 'Yes'].groupby(out["Date"].dt.quarter).count()
print(quarterly_churn_yes["Churn"])

Date
1    1154
2     114
3      68
4      69
Name: Churn, dtype: int64
```

This is used to calculate the churn rate groupby quarterly

```
total_churn = out['Churn'].count()
print(total_churn) 

quarterly_churn_rate = out.groupby(out["Date"].dt.quarter).apply(lambda x: quarterly_churn_yes["Churn"] / total_churn).sum()
print(quarterly_churn_rate)

Date
1    0.862159
2    0.085170
3    0.050803
4    0.051550
dtype: float64
```

The above code i have tried to the find churn rate grouped on date column querterly wise. I am getting 1,2,3,4 but i want year wise quarterly churn rate.

For example , if i have four years in the dataframe like 2018,2014,2017 in that

2008

```
1    1154
2     114
3      68
4      69
```

2014

```
1    1154
2     114
3      68
4      69
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is not a coding service. Please clearly state your problem, do some research and try something a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-01','2015-05-01','2015-07-01','2015-10-01','2015-04-01','2015-12-01','2016-01-01','2016-02-01','2015-05-01', '2015-10-01']), 'Churn': ['Yes'] * 8 + ['No'] * 2 })
print (out)
  Churn       Date
0   Yes 2015-01-01
1   Yes 2015-05-01
2   Yes 2015-07-01
3   Yes 2015-10-01
4   Yes 2015-04-01
5   Yes 2015-12-01
6   Yes 2016-01-01
7   Yes 2016-02-01
8    No 2015-05-01
9    No 2015-10-01
```

---

```
df = (out.loc[out['Churn'] == 'Yes']
         .groupby([out["Date"].dt.year,out["Date"].dt.quarter])["Churn"]
         .count()
         .rename_axis(('year','quarter'))
         .reset_index(name='count'))

print(df)
   year  quarter  count
0  2015        1      1
1  2015        2      2
2  2015        3      1
3  2015        4      2
4  2016        1      2
```

For separate DataFrames by years is possible create `dictionary of DataFrames`:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(out.groupby(out['Date'].dt.year)))
print (dfs)
{2016:   Churn       Date
6   Yes 2016-01-01
7   Yes 2016-02-01, 2015:   Churn       Date
0   Yes 2015-01-01
1   Yes 2015-05-01
2   Yes 2015-07-01
3   Yes 2015-10-01
4   Yes 2015-04-01
5   Yes 2015-12-01
8    No 2015-05-01
9    No 2015-10-01}

print (dfs.keys())
dict_keys([2016, 2015])

print (dfs[2015])
  Churn       Date
0   Yes 2015-01-01
1   Yes 2015-05-01
2   Yes 2015-07-01
3   Yes 2015-10-01
4   Yes 2015-04-01
5   Yes 2015-12-01
8    No 2015-05-01
9    No 2015-10-01


Tenure column looks like this

out["tenure"].unique() 
Out[14]: 
array([ 8, 15, 32,  9, 48, 58, 10, 29,  1, 66, 24, 68,  4, 53,  6, 20, 52,
       49, 71,  2, 65, 67, 27, 18, 47, 45, 43, 59, 13, 17, 72, 61, 34, 11,
       35, 69, 63, 30, 19, 39,  3, 46, 54, 36, 12, 41, 50, 40, 28, 44, 51,
       33, 21, 70, 23, 16, 56, 14, 62,  7, 25, 31, 60,  5, 42, 22, 37, 64,
       57, 38, 26, 55])
```

It contains no of months, it seems like 1 to 72.

I need to split tenure column into "range".

For example, this column contains 1 to 72 numbers, need to range up to 4 range.

```
like 1 to 18 --> 1 range
     19 to 36 --> 2nd range
     37 to 54 --> 3rd range like that
```

here i found quarterlywise churn count and with that churn count later i found churn rate with churn count and total count.

```
quarterly_churn_yes = out.loc[out['Churn'] == 'Yes'].groupby([out["Date"].dt.year,out["Date"].dt.quarter]).count().rename_axis(('year','quarter'))
quarterly_churn_yes["Churn"]

quarterly_churn_rate = out.groupby(out["Date"].dt.quarter).apply(lambda x: quarterly_churn_yes["Churn"] / total_churn).sum()
print(quarterly_churn_rate)
```

Like this I need to find tenure wise 4 range to find churn count.

Comment: It is working. but i need some confirmation like for 2008 it has 1st quarter right , it contains jan,feb,march ? or it is taking randomly?

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - Yes, it contains `jan, feb, march`.

Comment: can you please tell me how to cross verify that?

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar + give me a sec.

Comment: take your time please

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - You can check all months by year by `print (out.loc[(out['Date'].dt.year == 2015), 'Date'].dt.month)`

Comment: If need return only unique values `print (out.loc[(out['Date'].dt.year == 2015), 'Date'].dt.month.unique())`

Comment: How to do same process with "tenure" column, i am using telecom dataset. instead of year need to split into 4 range with tenure column

Comment: Do you think `4` DataFrames?

Comment: No, i dont want to use date column. Now , I want to use tenure column which contains number between 1 to 72.

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - I have no your data, what is tenure column?

Comment: check the last edit, i have numbers in that column i need to range those number into 4 parts

Comment: I get you, give em a sec.

Comment: Use `print (out.groupby(out['Date'].dt.year)['tenure'].unique())`

Comment: How about this one ? print (out.groupby(out['Date'].dt.quarter)['tenure'].count())
Date
1    4429
2     431
3     252
4     242
Name: tenure, dtype: int64

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - If need count by quarter, it is perfectly OK :)

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar My code return unique values of column `tenure` per year

Comment: actually i need to split into 4 ranges, for tat quarter is fine rit? after i find this count value need to apply for finding churn rate

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - I dont understand. What kind of ranges? Can you explain more?

Comment: The simpliest for me is created expected output from `out = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-01','2015-05-01','2015-07-01','2015-10-01','2015-04-01','2015-12-01','2016-01-01','2016-02-01','2015-05-01', '2015-10-01']), 'Churn': ['Yes'] * 8 + ['No'] * 2 })`

Comment: please wait let me check  and tell you the exact scenario

Comment: kindly check the last edit , this is my exact scenario

Comment: I think need `arr = np.array([ 8, 15, 32,  9, 48, 58, 10, 29,  1, 66, 24, 68,  4, 53,  6, 20, 52,
       49, 71,  2, 65, 67, 27, 18, 47, 45, 43, 59, 13, 17, 72, 61, 34, 11,
       35, 69, 63, 30, 19, 39,  3, 46, 54, 36, 12, 41, 50, 40, 28, 44, 51,
       33, 21, 70, 23, 16, 56, 14, 62,  7, 25, 31, 60,  5, 42, 22, 37, 64,
       57, 38, 26, 55])` and then 
`print (np.split(np.sort(arr), 4))` - check https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html

Comment: is there any solution to do this dynamically?

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - why think `np.split` is not dynamic solution? Can you explain more?

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar  - I have problem. I dont understand `Churn`. So I have no idea how I can help you. So explanation with `quarterlywise churn count` and `churn rate` is nothing :(

Comment: we found how to split into 4 range for tenure column right? in that we have 4 range right? i need to group churn column based in this tenure range

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - It seems undersand it.

Comment: you have an idea how to group the churn column based on this tenure range?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167088/discussion-between-sangeetha-sivakumar-and-jezrael).

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - Do you think `groupby([out["Date"].dt.year, out["Date"].dt.quarter, out['Tenure'] % 4])` ? If values between `1-72` it should create 4 groups

Comment: It should be in a range like 1 to 18 , 19 to 36 like that not based on date column quarter wise. 1 to 18 is some sort of people , 19 to 36 will be some sort of people like that

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - I dont understand, sorry. try create new question :(

Comment: Hi @jezrael. can we split the whole dataset based on one particular column that is "tenure column"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49376781/how-to-split-the-whole-dataset-into-4-range-based-on-one-column-using-python @jezrael

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - I check it and Tony solution looks what you need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383494/how-to-choose-the-best-model-dynamically-using-python @ jezrael

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar - Thank you, but I have no idea, never working with it before. Sorry.