# How to split the whole dataset into 4 range based on one column using python

Tags: python, split, dataset

I have a dataset with `7k records [telecom dataset]`.

I want to split that dataset into 4 range based on one particular column `["tenure column"]`, which contains 1 to 72 number.

Need to split the whole data based on this tenure column like:-

> 1 to 18 Range [1-dataset], 19 to 36 Range [2-dataset], 37 to 54 Range [3-dataset], 55 to 72 Range[4-dataset]

My sample dataset with head(5)

```
out.head(5)
Out[51]: 
   customerID      Date  gender  age  region  SeniorCitizen  Partner  \
0  9796-BPKIW  1/2/2008       1   57       1              1        0   
1  4298-OYIFC  1/4/2008       1   50       2              0        1   
2  9606-PBKBQ  1/6/2008       1   85       0              1        1   
3  1704-NRWYE  1/9/2008       0   55       0              1        0   
4  9758-MFWGD  1/6/2008       0   52       1              1        1   

   Dependents  tenure  PhoneService  ...    DeviceProtection  TechSupport  \
0           0       8             1  ...                   0            0   
1           0      15             1  ...                   1            1   
2           0      32             1  ...                   0            0   
3           0       9             1  ...                   0            0   
4           1      48             0  ...                   0            0   

   StreamingTV  StreamingMovies  Contract  PaperlessBilling  PaymentMethod  \
0            0                0         0                 1              1   
1            1                1         0                 1              2   
2            0                1         0                 1              2   
3            1                0         0                 1              2   
4            0                0         1                 0              0   

   MonthlyCharges  TotalCharges  Churn  
0           69.95        562.70      0  
1          103.45       1539.80      0  
2           85.00       2642.05      1  
3           80.85        751.65      1  
4           29.90       1388.75      0
```

Comment: Do you need 4 different data frames out of it?

Comment: I am not very clear about your question, but looks like you want to do df[df["tenure column].isin(range(1,19))]

Comment: yes @ AKS i need 4 dataframes

Comment: @Aritesh is there any dynamic way to do this same?

Comment: dflist = [df[df["tenure column].isin(range(i*18 + 1,(i+1)*18+1))] for i in range(4)]  - this will give you a list of dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas to easily do this thing.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_dataset_file.csv', sep=',', header=0)
# Sort it according to tenure
df.sort_values(by=['tenure'], inplace=True)
# Create bin edges 
step_size = int(df.tenure.max()/4)
bin_edges = list(range(0,df.tenure.max()+step_size, step_size))
lbls = ['a','b','c','d']
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df.tenure,bin_edges, labels= lbls)
# Create separate dataframes from it
df1 = df[df.bin == 'a']
df2 = df[df.bin == 'b']
df3 = df[df.bin == 'c']
df4 = df[df.bin == 'd']
```

Comment: without specifying the range, any dynamic way to do this?

Comment: how to separate that into 4 dataframe based on this bin column?

Comment: df1 = out[out.bin == 'a']
df2 = out[out.bin == 'b']
df3 = out[out.bin == 'c']
df4 = out[out.bin == 'd']


df1
Out[108]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [customerID, Date, gender, age, region, SeniorCitizen, Partner, Dependents, tenure, PhoneService, MultipleLines, InternetService, OnlineSecurity, OnlineBackup, DeviceProtection, TechSupport, StreamingTV, StreamingMovies, Contract, PaperlessBilling, PaymentMethod, MonthlyCharges, TotalCharges, Churn, bin]
Index: []

[0 rows x 25 columns]

Comment: It is only displaying the column names

Comment: great :) I am sry thats my mistake @ Tony

Answer (score 1):

I will create list of datasets

```
dflist = [df[df["tenure column"].isin(range(i*18 + 1,(i+1)*18+1))] for i in range(4)]
```

Comment: It is also working for me. But need to split as a separate dataframe after this

Comment: use dflist[i], all these are separate dataframes

Comment: dflist = [out[out["tenure"].isin(range(i*18 + 1,(i+1)*18+1))] for i in range(4)]
dflist[i]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-124-fe0a4abd57c3>", line 2, in <module>
    dflist[i]

NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Comment: First row will remain same, it will create dflist, now when you need to access 4 datasets, access them using, dflist[0], dflist[1], dflist[2] and dflist[3]

Answer (score 0):

Easy to understand code

```
i = 1
m = 0
out["tenure column"] = out["tenure column"].astype(int)
df = [None]*4
while i<72:
   df[m] = out[(out["tenure column"]>=i) & (out["tenure column"]<=(i+17))]
   m += 1
   i += 18
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 24, placement implies 1 Iam getting this  error