# How to choose the best model dynamically using python

Tags: python, models

Here is my code im building 6 models and i am getting accuracy in that, how do i choose that dynamically which accuracy is greater and i want to execute only that model which as highest accuracy.

```
"prepare configuration for cross validation test harness"

seed = 7

"prepare models"

models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression()))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('RF',RandomForestClassifier()))

#models.append(('SVM', SVC()))

"evaluate each model in turn"

results = []
names = []
scoring = 'accuracy'
for name, model in models:
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, orginal_telecom_80p_test[features], orginal_telecom_80p_test["Churn"], cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

This is my accuracy

```
LR: 0.787555 (0.039036)
LDA: 0.780460 (0.039821)
KNN: 0.759916 (0.030417)
CART: 0.706669 (0.035827)
NB: 0.731637 (0.050813)
RF: 0.752054 (0.048660)
```

Comment: The way you're doing the `for`, it's not gonna work. Use `enumerate()` on your models. It should look like this: `for index, model in enumerate(models): ...`. and you sould adapt your code to use the enumeration.

Comment: This should be simplified to a MCVE - there's a LOT of totally irrelevant code here.

Comment: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting iam getting this error @Doug

Comment: The confidence interval is given by ```scores.mean() - scores.std() * 2```: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation

So maybe store each model in the tuple keyed by their confidence % and sort in descending order?

Comment: Also your question is rather unclear. What is 'accuracy' here, and what do you mean by "i want to execute only that model which as highest accuracy" ?

Comment: yes i want to execute only one model which is having highest accuracy among this

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar, Looks like the exception is raised where you're defining your msg there, which you have 3 formaters, but you filling them with 2 arguments. Example: `"%s: %f (%f)" % (first, second, third)`.

Comment: how to do that ? @ rpg711 , can you please breifly explain that

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar repeating the exact same sentence that is totally unclear for anyone but you won't make it clearer.

Comment: msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std()) @Doug 3 arguments only

Comment: "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting iam getting this error" :facepalm: Please LEARN TO PROPERLY ASK A QUESTION !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you question is "I have those objects for which I can get a 'score' and I want to select the one with the higher score", it's quite simple: store the scores along with the objects, sort this base on score and keep the one with the highest score:

```
import random

def get_score(model):
    # dumbed down example 
    return random.randint(1, 10)
 
 
class Model1(object):
    pass

class Model2(object):
    pass

class Model3(object):
    pass

models = [Model1, Model2, Model3]

# build a list of (score, model) tuples
scores = [(get_score(model), model) for model in models]

# sort it on score
scores.sort(key=item[0])

# get the model with the best score, which is the
# the second element of the last item
best = scores[-1][1]
```